# How to convert value assigned to variable as String

Tags: javascript

I have limited knowledge  of javascript,so hoping someone can help.
Tried w3 schools & stacko using Document.
This is a dumb question. 
We receive a variable value that outputs string without quotes.The string has spaces.
In the example below is it possible to add quotes to my string.
how do i use a input value without quotes and parse it as string? 
myvar = John doe
is it possible to add Quotes to a value assigned to a variable?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="param">my string</div>
    <div id="base64param"></div>
    <div id="encodeparam"></div>
    <div id="myframe"</div>
    <div id="myframe2"</div>
    <iframe id="myframe" src="" width="400" height="800" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
    <script>
      window.onload =  function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("param").innerHTML;
        var base64param = window.btoa(str);
        document.getElementById("base64param").innerHTML = "base64:" + base64param;   
        var encodeparam = encodeURIComponent(str);
        document.getElementById("encodeparam").innerHTML = "encoded:" + encodeparam;   
        var appurl = "http://localhost/index.jsp?param=";
        var furl = appurl + str;
        document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML = "URLwithout encode:" + furl;
        var burl = appurl + base64param;
        document.getElementById("myframe2").innerHTML = "URLwith encode:" + burl;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use two different type of quotes... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing variable, and want to add quotes:

```
var varWithQuotes = "\"" + oldVar + "\"";
```

The slash is an escape character and the plus sign is how to concatenate strings.